# blackberry hashmap

Tags: blackberry, hashmap

what is the equivalent of

```
LinkedHashMap < String, String > postMap = 
    new LinkedHashMap < String, String >();
```

for Java 1.4 for Blackberry? I am trying to make a hashmap

Answer (score 3):

Try [Hashtable](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/java/util/Hashtable.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent. Some additional collections-related classes are in `net.rim.device.api.util`, but nothing like hash map with predictable traversion order.
Depending on a task, you might be better off with just a Vector - if there are only couple of dozen entries. Memory is kind of more precious than CPU on BB. 
If performance is unacceptable, then simply put a wrapper around Hashtable and store own class with `class MyEntry { String key; String value; MyEntry prev,next; }` as values.

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to use LinkedHashMap in BlackBerry because I wanted to implement an LRU cache.

Unfortunately LinkedHashMap isn't supported in BB so I found a nice sample code to implement this using only HashTable:

[Generic LRU Cache](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/GenericLRUCache.htm)